# open marker reactjs onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

i am using reactjs and google maps in my project

i want to show some marker but when i click on my marker all my marker appear

i want to open only one marker at the time(onclick)
can you tell me what is wrong with my function ?

```
 const MapWithAMakredInfoWindow = compose(
        withStateHandlers(() => ({
            isOpen: false,
        }), {
            onToggleOpen: ({ isOpen }) => () => ({
                isOpen: !isOpen,
            })
        }),

        withScriptjs,
        withGoogleMap
    )(props =>
        <GoogleMap
            defaultZoom={8}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: 44.8350088, lng: -0.5872689999999999 }}
        >

            {this.state.PartenaireData.map(function (item, i) {
                if (item.coordinates.latitude && item.coordinates.longitude)
                    return (
                        <Marker
                            position={{ lat: item.coordinates.latitude, lng: item.coordinates.longitude }}
                            onClick={props.onToggleOpen}
                            key={i}
                        >
                            { (props.isOpen ) &&
                            <InfoWindow  onCloseClick={props.onToggleOpen}>
                                <div>
                                    <div>{item.titre}</div>
                                    <div >autre data</div>
                                </div>
                            </InfoWindow>}
                        </Marker>)
            })}


        </GoogleMap>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

`isOpen` and `onToggleOpen` should be properties of `Marker` not `GoogleMap`.

By passing them to `GoogleMap`, you made them global (same for all the markers). So setting `isOpen` to `true` will open all the markers.

May be something like this

```
const MapWithAMakredInfoWindow = compose(
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap
)(props =>
    <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={8}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 44.8350088, lng: -0.5872689999999999 }}
    >

        {this.state.PartenaireData.map(function (item, i) {
            if (item.coordinates.latitude && item.coordinates.longitude)
                return (
                    compose(
                        withStateHandlers(() => ({
                            isOpen: false,
                        }), {
                            onToggleOpen: ({ isOpen }) => () => ({
                                isOpen: !isOpen,
                            })
                        })
                    )(markerProps =>
                        <Marker
                            position={{ lat: item.coordinates.latitude, lng: item.coordinates.longitude }}
                            onClick={markerProps.onToggleOpen}
                            key={i}
                        >
                            {(markerProps.isOpen) &&
                                <InfoWindow onCloseClick={markerProps.onToggleOpen}>
                                    <div>
                                        <div>{item.titre}</div>
                                        <div >autre data</div>
                                    </div>
                                </InfoWindow>}
                        </Marker>
                    )
                );
        })}
    </GoogleMap>
);
```

Comment: i think this it it but the marker are not rendering anymore :/

Comment: You might need to change the code according to how your environment is setup, this answer is just for you to get an idea

Comment: I dont know your code setup to give 100% working code for you to copy paste :D